# Passing IP address with mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-proxy

I have Apache with `mod_proxy` passing requests to Tomcat. The trouble is, when I get client IP address associated with a request in web app hosted on Tomcat, it always returns 127.0.0.1.

Is it possible to have Apache pass the original IP address to Tomcat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The X-Forwarded-For environment variable should also be set by default with mod_proxy

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using mod_jk or mod_proxy_ajp if you're wanting to retain information about the original requests source ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration should include `ProxyPreserveHost On`, similar to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName public.server.name

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8180/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8180/
</VirtualHost>
```

---

See my [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956361/apache-tomcat-using-modproxy-instead-of-ajp/962928#962928) for more details.

Comment: It did not seem to work with what I needed it for. In the end I decided to go for the X- header. Thank you!

Comment: This answer refers to keeping the "public.server.name" on the outgoing request to `http://localhost:8180/` not making the client ip valid.